# Deadpool the PC game camera problems

Tags: deadpool

Alright, so I've got the "Deadpool" Marvel game now.  I loaded it up for the first time, and it worked well, I started a game in the lowest difficulty (having never played before).  The starting cutscene played, but then the screen went dark. I still had the health bar, and the "Press w to get off your ass" message, and even the objective panel opened.  Yet other than those, the screen was pure black.  All the "voice" boxes were popping up, and I "got off my ass" but it stayed black.  I've restarted it three times, to the same effect.  I re-installed on the 3rd.  Anyone else have this problem, or want to help me out?  Any patch out there for this problem??

Ah yes, forgot to mention.  I downloaded the game, it isn't a disc, in case that matters.

Comment: Sounds like a graphics card issue perhaps?

Comment: No, I've researched it, and my graphics card can handle the game.  Besides, even if it couldnt, I wouldnt be able to see anything.  Instead, I can see the health bar and the little boxes that represent the other voices in DP's head.  I'm pretty sure it's something to do with my copy of the game, but I dont know how to fix it, reinstalling did nothing.